# Menu that fill the entire page

Tags: css, sass

I know it's probably the dumbest question on StackOverflow, but I have a problem with my menu. I want it to be 100% of the page's height, but it's only 100% of the window.

Here is my uncompiled Sass (Compile it yourself if you don't like Sass):

```
    .nav
      position: relative
      z-index: 0
      width: 20vw
      height: 100vh
      background-color: #EEEEEE
```

If you need more information (HTML code, etc...) see this link http://codepen.io/arguiot/pen/RGQkmg

Comment: we need more. for example HTML structure will help

Comment: add a js fiddle or you sample code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to your fixed header. Add its height (`15vh`) as a `margin-top` to the `.nav`bar, and subtract that value from the all items `margin-top` inside the navbar to compensate that moving down.

```
.nav
  position: relative
  z-index: 0
  width: 20vw
  height: 100vh
  margin-top: 15vh
  background-color: #EEEEEE
.nav-title
  position: relative
  text-align: center
  font-size: 1.5em
  top: 5vh

.nav-content
  position: relative
  margin-top: 10vh
  text-align: center
  font-size: 1.5em
```

Here's an edited codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORQKQm

Comment: what's your html code? did you set all the elements in between .nav and body to 100% height?

Comment: My HTML code is on CodePen.io, here is the [link](http://codepen.io/arguiot/pen/RGQkmg)

Comment: please note my completely changed answer